# Width Percentage not centered

Tags: html, css

I have a little designing issue and I'm not sure how to solve this.

```css
body {
 background-color: #000000 !important;
}

#container {
 position: relative;
}

#overlay {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 5%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://paralyzed.scork.net/img/splasher.png" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" id="splash" border="0" />
  <div id="overlay">
    <img src="http://paralyzed.scork.net/img/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook" border="0" width="40" />&emsp;
    <img src="http://paralyzed.scork.net/img/instagram.svg" alt="Instagram" border="0" width="40" />&emsp;
    <img src="http://paralyzed.scork.net/img/youtube.svg" alt="YouTube" border="0" width="40">
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3obft6q8/2/)

I've got a main image and want to overlay some social media icons. So far, so good. But I'd like to have them responsive by using percentage as width/height. As soon as I'm doing that, the social media icons aren't centered anymore, they are moving to the left.

Do you have any ideas, how to solve this? Been working at this for several hours now and tried a lot of variations, but nothing worked for me.

My goal is to have larger icons on Desktop and smaller on mobile.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Hi, thanks, ... are considered noise](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed these styles

```
    #container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }

    img.abc {
      width: 100%;
    }

    #overlay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  width :100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3obft6q8/9/)

```css
body {
 background-color: #000000 !important;
}

#container {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

#overlay {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 5%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
  width :100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.bg-image {
  width: 100%;
}
#overlay-image {
 width: 10%;
}
```

```html
  <div id="container">
   <img src="http://paralyzed.scork.net/img/splasher.png" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto bg-image" id="splash" border="0" />
   <div id="overlay">
    <img src="http://paralyzed.scork.net/img/facebook.svg" alt="Facebook" border="0" id="overlay-image" />&emsp;
    <img src="http://paralyzed.scork.net/img/instagram.svg" alt="Instagram" border="0" id="overlay-image" />&emsp;
    <img src="http://paralyzed.scork.net/img/youtube.svg" alt="YouTube" border="0" id="overlay-image" />
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Okay but when I'm using percentage on the images now, they are not centered (maybe I wasn't able to explain my problem the right way :)

I updated my the fiddle with my problem and now uncentered icons https://jsfiddle.net/3obft6q8/8/

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks, you saved me a lot of nerves. I just removed the .bg-image again, because I don't want it to be 100% on Desktop. But the other changes did it for me.